# AWS CodeCommit does support Git LFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, cicd, git-lfs, aws-codecommit

I have existing project repo in gitlab. Since the gitlab is running in the server, we have the lfs objects in certain directory. My Doubt is AWS Codecommit does not have seperate server to store any lfs configurations as gitlab or bitbucket. I've to configure the lfs directory in AWS CodeCommit. My Question is "Does AWS CodeCommit supports Git LFS?". If yes,can someone explain how to configure AWS CodeCommit with Git LFS?